# Me explicarían en que consiste este código?

Tags: java, algoritmos

**Este es el código:**

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        int n,n1,n2,n3;
        int m1,m2,m3,m4;

         n=new Random().nextInt(7)+1;
         n1=new Random().nextInt(7)+1;
         n2=new Random().nextInt(7)+1;
         n3=new Random().nextInt(7)+1;

          m1=new Random().nextInt(7)+1;
          m2=new Random().nextInt(7)+1;
          m3=new Random().nextInt(7)+1;
          m4=new Random().nextInt(7)+1;

         txtpeso1.setText(Integer.toString(n));
         txtpeso2.setText(Integer.toString(n1));
         txtpeso3.setText(Integer.toString(n2));
         txtpeso4.setText(Integer.toString(n3));

         txtprecio1.setText(Integer.toString(m1));
         txtprecio2.setText(Integer.toString(m2));
         txtprecio3.setText(Integer.toString(m3));
         txtprecio4.setText(Integer.toString(m4));
         int capacidad;
               capacidad=Integer.parseInt(txtcapacidad.getText())+1;




         int  []peso={n,n1,n2,n3};
         int [] precio={m1,m2,m3,m4};

        /* precio=new int [4];
          peso=new int [4]; 
                 peso[0]=Integer.parseInt(txtpeso1.getText());
                 peso[1]=Integer.parseInt(txtpeso1.getText());
                 peso[2]=Integer.parseInt(txtpeso1.getText());
                 peso[3]=Integer.parseInt(txtpeso1.getText());

                      precio[0]=Integer.parseInt(txtprecio1.getText());
                      precio[1]=Integer.parseInt(txtprecio1.getText());
                      precio[2]=Integer.parseInt(txtprecio1.getText());
                      precio[3]=Integer.parseInt(txtprecio1.getText());*/

           txtfin.setText(""+calcular(capacidad, peso, precio));

    }                                          
    public static int calcular(int capacidad, int[] peso, int[] precio)
    { 


    int n=peso.length;
    int [][]k=new int[n+1][capacidad+1];

        for (int i=0;i<=n;i++) {
            for (int w=0;w<=capacidad;w++) {
                if(i==0 || w==0)
                k[i][w]=0;

                else
                    if(peso[i-1]<=w)
                        k[i][w]=Math.max(precio[i-1]+k[i-1][w-peso[i-1]],k[i-1][w]);
                else
                        k[i][w]=k[i-1][w];
           }
        }
            return k[n][capacidad];
```

Más específicamente no entiendo esta parte del código:

```
public static int calcular(int capacidad, int[] peso, int[] precio) {
 int n = peso.length;
 int[][] k = new int[n + 1][capacidad + 1];
 for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
  for (int w = 0; w <= capacidad; w++) {
   if (i == 0 || w == 0) k[i][w] = 0;
   else if (peso[i - 1] <= w) k[i][w] = Math.max(precio[i - 1] + k[i - 1][w - peso[i - 1]], k[i - 1][w]);
   else k[i][w] = k[i - 1][w];
  }
 }
 return k[n][capacidad];
}
```

Comment: que es lo que no entiendes?

Comment: Esa parte:

@PabloSimonDiEstefano

  `public static int calcular(int capacidad, int[] peso, int[] precio)
    { 


    int n=peso.length;
    int [][]k=new int[n+1][capacidad+1];

        for (int i=0;i<=n;i++) {
            for (int w=0;w<=capacidad;w++) {
                if(i==0 || w==0)
                k[i][w]=0;

                else
                    if(peso[i-1]<=w)
                        k[i][w]=Math.max(precio[i-1]+k[i-1][w-peso[i-1]],k[i-1][w]);
                else
                        k[i][w]=k[i-1][w];
           }
        }
            return k[n][capacidad];`

Comment: Por favor, introduce en el código comentarios rodeando la zona que no conoces. En los comentarios ese código se hace ininteligible.

Comment: Además de lo que dicen los compañeros, deberías añadir una pequeña descripción con lo que hace el código y qué no comprendes de la parte concreta que dices (¿no entiendes qué hace? ¿No entiendes por qué lo hace así? ¿No entiendes el uso de alguna función en particular?...)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int calcular(int capacidad, int[] peso, int[] precio) {
int n = peso.length; //Obtenemos la longitu del arreglo
int[][] k = new int[n + 1][capacidad + 1]; //crea una arreglo de dos posiciones y lo inicializa para que sea el valor de n+1 y la segunda posición sera de capacidad +1
for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) { //Se empieza el primer ciclo que va recorrerse el numero de veces de la longitud de peso
for (int w = 0; w <= capacidad; w++) {//Se empiza otro ciclo que va recorrerse el numero de veces de la variable capacidad
if (i == 0 || w == 0) k[i][w] = 0; //tenes este if pero no hace nada solo valida que todos sean cero pero no ninguna condicion que haga
else if (peso[i - 1] <= w) k[i][w] = Math.max(precio[i - 1] + k[i - 1][w  - peso[i - 1]], k[i - 1][w]); //
else k[i][w] = k[i - 1][w];
}
}
return k[n][capacidad];
}
```

Te comente el codigo en cada linea para explicartelo que hace cada cosa

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int calcular(int capacidad, int[] peso, int[] precio) {
    int n = peso.length; // cuantos items tiene el arreglo
    int[][] k = new int[n + 1][capacidad + 1]; //llena el arreglo k
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) { //primer ciclo recorre arreglo peso
        for (int w = 0; w <= capacidad; w++) { // segundo ciclo recorre k
             // aqui es donde ocurre la magia
            if (i == 0 || w == 0) {
                k[i][w] = 0;
            } else if (peso[i - 1] <= w) {
                k[i][w] = Math.max(precio[i - 1] + k[i - 1][w - peso[i - 1]], k[i - 1][w]);
            } else {
                k[i][w] = k[i - 1][w];
            }
        }
    }
    return k[n][capacidad];// acá es donde devuelve el resultado
}
```